# How do I make a custom form module in Drupal and make it appear in the add content type?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

Drupal at the moment is making me feel dumb but I am relentlessly pursuing it and need help right now.

My aim is to create a custom form inside table elements. After probing online and on stackoverflow, people recommended I dig deep into the forms api and build my own form module.

Now when I create a module and enable it, I am not able to see it when I click 'Add content type' like I would when I download the webform module and enable it appears automatically on my content creation form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your module has in it but you need to use the hook_node_info() to create a new content type.

Here's the documentation on the drupal website http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_info/7

It should be something like this

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_info().
 */
function mymodule_node_info() {
  return array(
    'blog' => array(
      'name' => t('MyModule entry'),
      'base' => 'mymodule',
      'description' => t('Description of content type'),
    )
  );
}
```